# How to draw a unit circle that's inscribed in a square in python using PIL

Tags: python, image, graphics, geometry, python-imaging-library

I want to draw 600x600 image, while looping through each pixel to draw a quarter of a circle (with a radius of pi). 
How do i color each pixel (xp, yp) differently depending on whether the corresponding coordinates (x, y) fall inside or outside the unit circle: x2 + y2 = 1, as in when I put an if statement, what condition do I use?

I'm trying to make a quarter of a circle that was incribed in a square
This is what I have so far:

```
from PIL import Image
img=Image.new('RGB',(600,600),(0,0,255))
yp = 0
while yp < 600:
   xp = 0
   while xp < 600:
      img.putpixel((xp,yp),(0,255,0))
      xp += 1
   yp += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You talk us about two radii, like ring -  right?

You need to use scale multiplier to fit circle with radius Pi onto the whole rectangle

```
Scale = 600 / Pi
```

and inside the loops check conditions:

```
if (xp * xp + yp * yp) < Scale * Scale:   #inside R=1 circle
   color = InnerColorConst
elif (xp * xp + yp * yp) < Scale * Scale * Pi * Pi:   #inside R=Pi circle 
   color = OuterColorConst
else:
  color = BackgroundColorConst    # or omit putpixel
```